How to find the correct "keystring" for an input keystroke in neovim?
I want to map the keystroke Ctrl + § to :Telescope oldfiles in neovim. I naively tried this:
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-§>', ':Telescope oldfiles<CR>', {noremap = true, silent = true })

but this doesn't work. This is my keyboard:

The keys I want to map are marked in red. How would I now go about finding out the correct "keymap string" I have to provide to nvim to recognise this combination?

Which terminal emulator are you using? If you execute showkey -a and then press this combo, what does it say? If it writes a two-character combo beginning with ^, e.g. ^Z, then it probably translates to <C-Z> (or whichever other symbol instead of Z in this example) in nvim's syntax.

I suspect you would have to use a Control Sequence Introducer (CSI) type sequence as the left-hand side (lhs) mapping in your vim.keymap.set command (see below for more info. on what lhs is). However, at present, Neovim does not support CSI sequences as lhs mappings. The enhancement request is currently being tracked under the issue #17108 on the Neovim GitHub repository.
To find out which sequence is being used inside your terminal, try one of the below, then press the key combination you desire and observe the output.

run cat
press Ctrl + v
run showkey -a

Once you know the sequence, you'd then use this as the lhs mapping in your vim.keymap.set command if/when that enhancement is added.
What is LHS and RHS in vim.keymap.set()?
lhs and rhs in the context of vim.keymap.set refers to the the left- and right-hand side of the key mapping function's signature, respectively:
vim.keymap.set({mode}, {lhs}, {rhs}, {opts})

By using this function, one maps lhs to rhs: where lhs is a string, and rhs can be a string or a function.

Ah very useful thank you! The answer could be improved by shortly explaining what lhs mapping is. And for example in my case I get an ^@ as an output. I once learned that ^  stands for ctrl. So what should my vim-binding be? <C-@> then? How do I generally translate this? Using ctrl-v to output special characters literally I can also press e.g. alt+a which gives me ^[a . Is there a lookup table on what all these special characters, ^, [, ... mean in the terminal context?

@glades I'll update with the additional information regarding the special characters shortly, but first, can you please enter insert mode within Neovim, and then press the Crtl  + § shortcut and report back what is inserted inside Neovim.

Hmm no specific character is inserted but the inserted text string from the last insert is repeated. So if I go to insert mode and press insert asdf<ESC>, the next time when I go to insert mode and hit <C-§>, another asdf<ESC> is inserted.

@glades It sounds like <C-§> might be mapped to the "insert previously inserted text" shortcut, <C-a>, or your keyboard/terminal is inputting <C-a> to Neovim when <C-§> is pressed. I'd disable all mappings in your configuration file and then check if <C-§> still does the insert.

Thx I figure this should do it!
